# Cannot Access class Error from given code?

Tags: java, class

I was given some pre-written classes called NGen which is a generic node class and Stack1Gen.java which is being implemented for a linked list. For some reason in the Stack1Gen class, I get an error when it says start.getNext(); saying "Cannot access NGen. What does this mean?

```
// NGen.java
// A *simplified* generic node class for use with Stack1Gen class 
// and other data structures as desired; uses generics for the data

public class NGen <T> {

    // constructors

    public NGen () {}

    public NGen (T o, NGen<T> link) {
        data = o;
        next = link;
    }

    // selectors

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T o) {
        data = o;
    }

    public NGen<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(NGen<T> link) {
        next = link;
    }

    // instance variables

    private T data;
    private NGen<T> next;

}  // NGen class



// Stack1Gen.java
// The StackGen Interface is implemented using linked list
// The linked list used is a simple generic node class called NGen.  (See NGen.java)

public class Stack1Gen <T> implements StackGen<T> {

    // constructor

    public Stack1Gen () {}

    // selectors

    public void push(T o) {
        start = new NGen<T>(o, start);
    }

    public T pop() {
        if (start == null)
          throw new RuntimeException("Tried to pop an empty stack");
        else {
          T data = start.getData();
          start = start.getNext();
          return data;
        }
    }

    public T top() {
        if (start == null)
          return null;
        else return start.getData();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (start == null)
          return true;
        else return false;
    }

    // instance variables

    private NGen<T> start = null;

}  // Stack1Gen class
```

Comment: Your code compiles just fine, provided I add a fake version of the `StackGen` interface (which you haven't included in your post).

Answer (score 0):

There is no errors in your code. If you are using Intellij IDEA try "invalidate cache and restart" (from File menu)